# Как в C правильно форматировать время?

Tags: c

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat buff;


    if (!(dir = opendir(name))){
        return;
      }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            //char path[1024];

            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0){
                continue;
              }
              //
              stat(entry->d_name, &buff);

              time_t times = buff.st_ctim.tv_sec;

              printf("%s %s", entry->d_name, ctime(&times)); //

              listdir(entry->d_name, indent + 1);



        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении выдает время ctime не корректно, все идет с 1970 года. Получается так: Thu Jan  1 05:03:14 1970
Проблема в форматировании времени?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "*правильно форматировать*"? Особенно если учесть, что отсчет того же `time()` и иже с ним идет от "начала эпохи Unix" — с 00:00:00 1 января 1970 года.

Comment: Я видимо не понимаю, почему он выдает время с начала эпохи в. Т.е должен быть текущий год. Значит проблема с &times ?

Comment: Хотел скомпилировать ваш код, но под Visual C++ он не компилируется, тут другие определения `stat`, другие поля. Так что как совет - посмотрите вашу документацию. У меня похожий код `struct stat buff;  stat("myfile.txt", buff); time_t times = buff.st_ctime; printf(" %s", ctime(&times));` дает правильное локальное время.

Comment: Да буду рыться в документации под Linux

Comment: у меня все в норме, система Fedora. Есть вариант, просто посмотреть из командной строки время создания (команда stat) или в mc

Comment: да, можно сделать самое простое, вывести на печать чему равно times. Да и еще, times есть такая функция

Comment: @DimaKuzmin, с виду всё правильно и УМВР... возможно, ты пытаешься запустить программу на какой-то странной ФС не поддерживающей `ctime`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо у вас какая-то наведенная ошибка, поскольку вы не обходите дерево оглавлений, но рекурсивно вызываете `listdir()` и не проверяете результата вызова `stat()`.

У меня

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-xubu2 5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 20:27:37 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

ваш код с минимальными изменениями (**пара `chdir()` для обхода дерева**) вполне успешно работает.

```
void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat buff;


    if (!(dir = opendir(name))){
      perror(name);
      return;
    }
    chdir(name); // думаю, тут можно и не проверять результат, т.к. предыдущий `opendir()` успешно прошел

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            //char path[1024];

            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0){
                continue;
              }
              //
              stat(entry->d_name, &buff);

              time_t times = buff.st_mtim.tv_sec; //buff.st_ctim.tv_sec;

              printf("%s %s", entry->d_name, ctime(&times)); //

              listdir(entry->d_name, indent + 1);



        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    chdir("..");
}
```

Для соответствия формата времени тому, что выводит `ls -l` я заменил `st_ctim` (*в manpage это "Time of last status change"*) на `st_mtim` (*"Time of last modification"*).

Comment: Да, действительно твой вариант работает. Спасибо.